# Using ThreadStart my UI stuck

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I'm new to threading 
my UI is not responding till completion of process. any one tell me what's wrong here.

reduced code:

```
  static string replacedname = "", replacedwith;
            private void startProcess(string FPath, string RNo)
            {
                if (FPath != "" && RNo != "")
                {
                    ....

                    UnZip(FPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(FPath) + "\\" + replacedwith);

                    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(FPath) + "\\" + replacedwith);
                    foreach (FileInfo File1 in dir.GetFiles("*.zip"))
                    {
                        UnZip(File1.FullName, Path.GetDirectoryName(File1.FullName));
                        File.Delete(File1.FullName);
                    }

                }

                replacedname = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Completed");

            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                ThreadStart threadStart = delegate() { startProcess(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text); };

                threadStart.BeginInvoke(null, null);


            }
            private void UnZip(string zipToExtract, string unzipDirectoryl) // Extract zip/lot file in same directory
            {

                if (this.progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { UnZip(zipToExtract, unzipDirectoryl); }));

                }
                else if (this.label3.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    label3.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { UnZip(zipToExtract, unzipDirectoryl); }));
                }
                else
                {                        ....
                            progressBar1.Value += 1;
                            progressBar1.Refresh();
                            label3.Text = ((progressBar1.Value * 100) / (progressBar1.Maximum)).ToString();
                            label3.Refresh();
                        ...
                }
            }


            private void status(string msg, Color selcColor)
            {
                if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { status(msg, selcColor); }));
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                    var oldcolor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;

                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = selcColor;
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(msg + "\n");
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = oldcolor;
                    richTextBox1.Refresh();
                    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                }
            }
```

Comment: a) way too much code.

Comment: b) try replacing Control.Invoke with Control.BeginInvoke

Comment: too much code here, in anyway this site is not for "debug my code"

Comment: @HenkHolterman if i use Begin-invoke its working in another thread. i need to working in sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadStart threadStart = delegate() { startProcess(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text); };
            threadStart.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }
```

with

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadStart threadStart = delegate() { startProcess(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text); };
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
            thread.Start();
        }
```

This will start a new thread with the delegate you assigned.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2.aspx) for MSDN reference.

**EDIT**

In your `UnZip`-method you are doing something strange

```
private void UnZip(string zipToExtract, string unzipDirectoryl){

            if (this.progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { UnZip(zipToExtract, unzipDirectoryl); }));

            }
            else if (this.label3.InvokeRequired) // why else if on another control???
            {
                label3.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { UnZip(zipToExtract, unzipDirectoryl); }));
            }
            else
            {                        ....
                        progressBar1.Value += 1;
                        progressBar1.Refresh(); //why use Refresh()?
                        label3.Text = ((progressBar1.Value * 100) / (progressBar1.Maximum)).ToString();
                        label3.Refresh();
                    ...
            }
        }
```

You can't call `progressbar1.InvokeRequired` and if it returns false use `else if` on the Label-control!
You must use separate `if/else` for every control.

```
if (this.progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
     progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { progressbar1.Value++; }));
else 
     progressbar1.Value++; //pseudo-code
```

Comment: its still the same as previous. Both are executing but my UI is not responding in long time process

Comment: With all the `...` I don't know all of your code. It is strange behavior, though!

Answer (score 0):

You should use BackgroundWorker Control for asynchronous operations in WinForms. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) MSDN artical for its usage details and example.